# Como imprimir variável em componente do componente no Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, variáveis, laravel-blade, componentes

Eu tenho uma variável $usuarioBiografia no meu Controller. Assim:

```
public function index()
    {
        $userBiografia = "Biografia do Usuário";
        return view('user.index', compact('userBiografia'));
    }
```

Eu consigo imprimir ela tranquilamente na View "user.index" utilizando:

```
{{ $userBiografia }}
```

Até aí ok!

O grande **PROBLEMA** é: Eu não consigo usar essa variável dentro dos meus componentes.
A minha estrutura de componentes está assim:

```
{{ $userBiografia }} //Aqui estou imprimindo na View, ok, mas não é aqui que quero fazer isso.
<div class="profile-sidebar pd-lg-r-25">
   <div class="row">
      @component('user.components.sidebar_left.index')
      @endcomponent
   </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- profile-sidebar -->
```

e dentro desta componente eu chamo uma nova componente que é onde de fato a variável será impressa.

Quem puder ajudar eu agradeço muito, porque não achei nada a respeito.

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa passar como parâmetro do método @component.

Veja se esto exemplo pode te ajudar.

```
@component('component.pagination', ['collection' => $students, 'class' => 'student-pagination'])
```

Comment: Eu acabei por colocar tudo neste formato: "<x-userSidebarLeftWidgetBiografia />", daí criei uma View, em App, pelo próprio Artisan. Lá eu estou fazendo todo o tratamento dos dados. Gostei pq o código na Blade fica limpo. Não sei se deu pra entender kkk mas o vídeo foi esse [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQWeTnOwlm4&t=492s)

Comment: Ahhh sim, obrigado Barttolo!